# Is there any method or macro to simulate syntax "if(a <= b < c <= ...)" to replace "if(a<=b && b < c && c <= ...)"?

Tags: c++, syntax

I want to find a method or macro which `a <= b && b < c` can rewrite as `a <= b < c`, because `a <= b < c` seems more straight forward and often seen in user requirement definition. Also `a <= b && b < c` needs to type `b` twice.

I searched about operators, but it seems (I think) only can add operation for custom class, but not alter the original operation. Also I know I can overload `bool operator >` but not sure I can add a new operation `int operator >` which returns the larger one. Also even operator overload works, `a <= b < c` will return c only, but not the true or false of statement `a <= b < c` (similar to `MAX(c, MAX(b, a))`).

Is there any method to simulate `a <= b < c <= ...`?

Comment: I think to most C++ programmers `a <= b < c` would look like a potential bug, because they are used to seeing `a<=b && b < c`.

Comment: The only way to distort the language that way is to overload the first operator to return an object that overload the next operator and so on. However I suggest you don't do that, because it might be obvious to you right now, but not to others, and that "others" might include yourself in a year.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12658124/how-to-implement-3-x-10-in-c/12658241

Comment: You might be able to write a macro like `COMPARE(a, <=, b, <, c)` but ugh. A template function `compare(a, cmp_le, b, cmp_lt, c)` would be easier ...

Answer (score 0):

The comments already note it's a bad idea so I won't repeat that.

It's somewhat possible with macro's. None of those operators can be a macro name. But if you'd allow `BADIDEA(a<=b<c)`, you can expand that as `HelperClass()*a<=b<c`. The idea is that `Helperclass::operator*` has the highest precendence. That means we parse it as `HelperClass::operator*(HelperClass(), a)`.

This first part returns another `HelperClass`. `HelperClass` also overloads `operator<=` so we next get `HelperClass::operator<=(firstExpr, b)`.

In this way, we can build a list of arguments passed to `HelperClass` It even supports `BADIDEA(a<b<c<d)`. In the end, we just call `HelperClass::operator bool` which returns `true` if and only if the list of arguments is sorted.

ALternatively, you don't need to build the list of arguments, but can immediately evaluate them. `HelperClass()*4<3` can already evaluate to `false` before you see `<=7` in `HelperClass()*4<3<=7`