# Possible meaning of x > y > new T : syntax

Tags: c++, c++11, comparison, comparison-operators

I was reading [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/570638/Ten-Cplusplus-Features-Every-Cplusplus-Developer) about the most useful C++11 features and I bumped into this chunk of code in the last section:

```
 if(_size != copy._size)
 {
    _buffer = nullptr;
    _size = copy._size;
    _buffer = _size > 0 > new T[_size] : nullptr;
 }
```

I was used to consider the last line as `(_size > 0) > other_Value` but in this case the right operand is a `new` declaration. I really cannot understand the sense of it. Also, what does the `: nullptr` refer to? Is there something which is initialised to `nullptr`? If yes, what?

Comment: Only as a information not strictly related to your post - a question about implementing `a < b < c` is already present in SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12658124/how-to-implement-3-x-10-in-c

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think, that it's wrong snippet. It should be

```
_buffer = _size > 0 ? new T[_size] : nullptr;
```

that is basically ternary operator. If `_size` > 0, then memory for array of T of size `_size` will be allocated, in other case `nullptr` will be assigned to `_buffer`. And it's not C++11 feature, since in C++98 it can be just

```
_buffer = _size > 0 ? new T[_size] : 0; // or NULL, or (void*)0.
```

Comment: Jeez, now all makes sense. Thanks. It was literally driving me crazy.

Comment: Since `?` is just to the right of `>` on most (US) keyboards, it's a very imaginable typo.

Comment: @RDGuida If you are a registered user on that site I would suggest you leave a bug report on that.